# How to calculate this average?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

I'm not sure if there is a term for what I'm trying to calculate, but imagine that there is a game where a win rewards you *x* points and a loss rewards you *y* points.  If you happen to know that your win rate *w* for this game is 70%, how can you calculate what the average reward will be?  What is that formula?

Comment: What does your intuition tell you?

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out by myself?  Is this the correct formula?

$$x̄ = x\cdot w + y\cdot(1 - w)$$

Comment: And that's what we call expected value, well done.